# splitting string based on case insensitive sub-string

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I need to split a string based on a word. That word may be of any Case and I need to preserve the case of the array of sub strings. Example:

1. The string May be 
   a) "My name is XYZ and I live in ABC." OR 
   b) "My name is XYZ AND I live in ABC." OR 
   c) "My name is XYZ And I live in ABC."
2. Now, the separating string may be "and" OR "AND" OR "And".
3. In my code I am unaware of which string is used among a), b) and c).
4. The question is how do I separate the string to "My name is XYZ" and "I live in ABC." respectively.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@" and " options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

to find the location of the separating string in a case-insensitive way, and then
extract the first and last part with

```
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *first = [string substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSString *last = [string substringFromIndex:(range.location + range.length)];
} else {
    // separator not found ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
    NSString *string1 = @"My name is XYZ and I live in ABC.";
    NSRange range = [string1 rangeOfString:@"And" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *firstStr = [string1 substringToIndex:range.location];
        NSString *secondStr = [string1 substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];


        NSLog(@"firstString  : %@",firstStr);
        NSLog(@"SecondStr :  %@",secondStr);
    }
```

**Output**

firstString : My name is XYZ

SecondString : I live in ABC.

Comment: Test if string is present with `range.location != NSNotFound`.

Answer (score -1):

Do u know which word u will use as ur anchor to split ???

Assuming u do, and say its "AND".

Do this.

1. get main string.
2. create temp string as : `tempString = [mainString lowercaseString];`
3. then find range of ur anchor : `range = [tempString rangeOfSubstring:anchor];`
4. now that u have the range of ur anchor. Extract substrings from the main string using this range. How to do this. Think a bit and have fun :) :)

Comment: This will not work if the string contains letters that have different lengths in upper and lower case (example: german sharp s).

Comment: sorry man .. Didn't get you. How do strings have different lengths for uppercase and lowercase ??

Comment: German sharp s "ß" becomes "SS" in upper case. There are other examples.

Comment: Thnx man. Didn't know. But if it does, will this still work ?? `[string rangeOfString:@" and " options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

Comment: Of course. It's the same engine that would do the conversion to double s. It's aware of all these subtleties.